# How to split any string with maximum length using regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Here is my input

```
var input = "1234:D \n ABnCD\rE456 F\r\nGHIJ789\\nKL MNO012P QRST:) :-( aa:? aa *D* :)\r\nGHIJ789\nwww.ring.com ssd";
```

If the string length is more than `70`, then split it taking most character as possible without dividing any word. If there any possibility of word dividation then neglect the last word, which will be use for next segment.

I see a lot of example about this type. `string.Split(' ')` is one of them which may works. But I am looking something in C#

For regex this one is nearby my solution

```
var splitForRichTB = Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1,70})(?:\s|$)|(.{70})")
                                       .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                                       .ToList();
```

But It provide below output

1. `1234:D`
2. `ABnCD\rE456 F\r`  .....

   **Expecter Output**

   `1234:D \n ABnCD\rE456 F\r\nGHIJ789\\nKL MNO012P QRST:) :-( aa:? aa`
   `*D* :)\r\nGHIJ789\nwww.ring.com ssd`

**The input may be longer than I provide, It may be many times of 70**

Comment: This is not that clear. Please check http://ideone.com/5xicoe - is that what you want? Matching with `@".{1,70}(?!\S)"`? Or, do you want the `.` in the pattern to also match a newline ([like here](http://ideone.com/27hkgX))?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your requirements, but have you tried something simple as `if (input.Length > 70)` and using two patterns?

Comment: I Could get the regex you want but in .net it doesn't work idk why! [`(.{1,70}(?=\s|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/U4xnOb/1)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: This is exactly what I suggest, it is equivalent of `.{1,70}(?!\S)`. It is also much cleaner to use `Regex.Matches` rather than `Split`.

Comment: but in .net it doesn't split like that. with `Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1,70}(?=\s|$))");` it gives `11` strings with what ever logic. with your pattern it just gives `6` empty strings. am I misunderstanding something? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: I said splitting is not the cleanest way, I use matching in my code. When matching, the outer capturing group is redundant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew @M please check my `expected output`

Comment: Your first item ends with the 61st char, right? Then why do you say 70? See http://ideone.com/wGR3Qt (where I replaced `\r` with `\\R` and `\n` with `\\N` for demo purposes), Here is a splitting approach - http://ideone.com/AlwIhb

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no it should end with 67st char. Because it's nearest to 70. please check space

Comment: 67 is right before `)RNGHIJ` - http://ideone.com/RjGh3x

Comment: Rather than regular expressions, perhaps you should investigate algorithms used folding lines of text in the style of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(Unix)) program.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew                                                         [ideone.com/wGR3Qt](http://ideone.com/wGR3Qt) loss some data, if any substring length greater than 70.                       [ideone.com/AlwIhb](http://ideone.com/AlwIhb) this one take much time if there is no substring for split for long input

Answer (score 1):

I think **string.Split()**  is faster than **Regex.Split()** for my case. By getting all your helps I think below code is helpful for me. I share it if anyone think useful.

```
var input = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890@@@123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567@@@123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 @@khalil";

var richTextBoxList = new List<string>();
var maxLength = 70;
if (input.Length > maxLength )
{
    var splitedStr = input.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var tempStr = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in splitedStr)
    {
       if (tempStr.Length + item.Length < maxLength)
       {
          tempStr += item;
       }
       else if (tempStr.Length + item.Length > maxLength)
       {
           if (tempStr.Length > 0 && tempStr.Length < maxLength)
           {
               richTextBoxList.Add(tempStr);
               tempStr = item;
           }
           else
           {
               while (tempStr.Length > maxLength)
               {
                   var splitMax = tempStr.Substring(0, maxLength);
                   richTextBoxList.Add(splitMax);
                   tempStr = tempStr.Substring(maxLength);
                }
                tempStr = tempStr + item;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           richTextBoxList.Add(tempStr + item);
           tempStr = string.Empty;
        }
     }
     while (tempStr.Length > maxLength)
     {
        var splitMax = tempStr.Substring(0, maxLength);
        richTextBoxList.Add(splitMax);
        tempStr = tempStr.Substring(maxLength);
      }
      if (tempStr.Length > 0)
          richTextBoxList.Add(tempStr);
}
else
    richTextBoxList.Add(originalText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to split at spaces, then the best solution would be:

```
int lastSpaceIndex = input.LastIndexOf(' ', 70);
if (lastSpaceIndex != -1)
{
    var part = input.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
    // Your own code
}
else
{
    // No space or empty...
}
```

Since you want to get all strings, then you should have a loop and use the `Substring` overload that accept a `count` so you would not need to copy the remaining part of the string on each iteration.

And it might be a good idea to return an `IEnumerable<string>` so that if you don't need all the data at once, you would not allocate memory for all lines.

If however you want to split at other characters, then you should use `LastIndexOfAny` instead.

Also, if you want to keep existing line, the first step would be to find the next line change.

```
var lineChars = new char[] { '\r', '\n' };
var nextLineIndex = input.IndexOfAny(lineChars, 0, 70);
```

When all this information, actual code is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this for one or multiple splitters**:

**Note to the method expecting a list of splitters**:
 If you have one splitter containing the other one ("\r\n" containing "\n"), the occurence of the splitter is counted from the *beginning* of that splitter, so if your line ends with "\r\n", then the splitter "\n" will be counted as last and "\r" will stay part of that line while "\n" will be left out since it served its purpose.

**Note to the Debug output**: 
Obviously the "\n" characters will be output as newline, not as "\n".

**Note to Input without splitter within maxLen**: If no splitter can be found within the range of maxLen, the string is just split at maxLen.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var input = "1234:D \n ABnCD\rE456 F\r\nGHIJ789\\nKL MNO012P QRST:) :-( aa:? aa *D* :)\r\nGHIJ789\nwww.ring.com ssd";

        var withMultipleSplitters = SplitStrings(new List<string>() {"\n", " ", "\r\n"}, 70, input);
        var withOneSplitter = SplitStrings(" ", 70, input);

        Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Content of: {nameof(withMultipleSplitters)}");
        foreach (string s in withMultipleSplitters)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Content of: {nameof(withOneSplitter)}");
        foreach (string s in withOneSplitter)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    private List<string> SplitStrings(List<string> splitters, int maxLen, string input)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            if (input.Length < maxLen)
            {
                output.Add(input);
                break;
            }

            int last = -1;
            int splitterLen = 0;
            foreach (string splitter in splitters)
            {
                int splitIndex = input.LastIndexOf(splitter, maxLen);
                if (last < splitIndex)
                {
                    last = splitIndex;
                    splitterLen = splitter.Length;
                }
            }

            if (last == -1)
            {
                last = maxLen;
            }

            string sub = input.Substring(0, last);
            input = input.Substring(last + splitterLen); 
            output.Add(sub);
        }

        return output;
    }

    private List<string> SplitStrings(string splitter, int maxLen, string input)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            if (input.Length < maxLen)
            {
                output.Add(input);
                break;
            }

            int last = input.LastIndexOf(splitter, maxLen);

            if (last == -1)
            {
                last = maxLen;
            }

            string sub = input.Substring(0, last);
            input = input.Substring(last + splitter.Length);
            output.Add(sub);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Split with 30 character limit:**

```
string s = @"1.3#, 2.99, 3\t, 4#2/2/1019#, 5, asd, Howdy, Howdy, Howdy, a;sdlkf";<br>
string[] myValues = Regex.Split(s, @"(.{1,30}(?=\s|$))");<br>
foreach (string s1 in myValues)<br>
    Console.WriteLine(s1);<br>
```

**Result:**

```
1.3#, 2.99, 3\t, 4#2/2/1019#,<br>
5, asd, Howdy, Howdy, Howdy,<br>
a;sdlkf
```

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior of the `.` is not to match the newline `\n`.
That's why your parts end there.

Either you add the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option <strike>or you replace the `.` with `(.|\n)`</strike>.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: How so? How I understand the question the OP wants to split a text in parts with maximum length of 70 without splitting in the middle of a word. He already has an regular expression that is "nearby his solution", but keeps him with too short chunks. Apperently because there are newline characters in his text. Forcing the regex to match newline characters would help. - Want did I get wrong?

Comment: Never suggest `(.|\n)` - the worst NFA regex construct in the world. `RegexOptions.Singleline` is the only appropriate way to match any char with `.`.

Comment: @RobinKoch if I use `RegexOptions.Singleline` then it remove new line character `\n`. which I need in next step. to create paragraph.